# Ring-isomorphism between factor ring and ring of continous function

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

This an exercise from Serge Lang, *Real and Functional Analysis*, Springer, 3rd edition (1993), chapter 3, page 59.

Let $S$ be a closed subset of a Hausdorff space $X$ and $R= C(X)$ be the ring of continous functions (real ou complex valued). Show that the set $J$ of all $f \in R$ such that $f$ vanishes on $S$ is a closed ideal. Establish a ring-isomorphism between the factor ring $R/J$ and $C(S)$.

I was able to prove that $J$ is a closed ideal. My doubt is about the ring-isomorphism. I could not find one. I was just able to find one supposing $X$ normal. I did the following:

Define
$$\phi: R \rightarrow C(S) $$
$$ f \mapsto \left. f \right|_S,$$

which is a homomorphism of rings. Notice that $\ker \phi = J$. If $X$ is normal, then we can extend any function in $C(S)$ to a continous function in $X$ by the Tietze Extension Theorem. Thus, $\phi(R) = C(S)$. By the first isomorphism theorem,
$$\bar\phi: R/J \rightarrow C(S) $$
$$ f + J \mapsto \left. f \right|_S$$
is a ring-isomorphism. Does someone know how to do it just supposing $X$ Hausdorff or is there a counterexample?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say the set of all f in C(X) which vanish on S?

Comment: Yes, I am gonna fix it! Thanks.

Comment: The exercise you mention is under a chapter entitled "Continuous functions on compact sets".  I would therefore assume there is a blanket assumption that $X$ is compact and Lang is adding the hypothesis that $X$ is Hausdorff in this specific exercise.  Otherwise I very  much doubt it is possible to prove it without some extra assumptions.

Comment: @Ruy yeah maybe you are right. That also would solve the problem, because a compact Hausdorff space is normal. However, in the other exercises in this chapter, he specified that the space is compact.

Comment: Here is another indication that Lang thinks of $X$ as a compact space: the exercise calls for proving that $J$ is CLOSED, and the only norm on $C(X)$ discussed in that chapter is the sup norm, which is only defined if $X$ is compact.